# View not updating on data change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm currently working on a **notification plugin** in my project. I want every component to be able to trigger a notification like this:

```js
this.$notification({
   msg: 'error message'
});
```

To achieve that, I created a following plugin with a component:

**Notifications.js**

```js
import Notifications from './Shared/Components/Notifications';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
    install: (app, options) => {
        app.component('notifications', Notifications)

        Vue.prototype.$notification = function (options) {
            Notifications.methods.show(options);
        }
    },
}
```

**Notifications.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>
      {{ message }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Notifications",
    data() {
        return {
            message: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show(options) {
            this.message = options.msg;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But now, when another component triggers the plugin the view of the notifications.vue component does not change. But if I log the new value `this.message` it shows the new value. How do I achieve, that the new message "error message" is shown?

I already tried to **watch** the property, but it does not get triggered.

Comment: Why don't you use Vuex for that? You can store a new message and show it in Notifications component

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `Notifications.methods.show(options)` since there's no Notifications component instance.

Comment: @DecadeMoon It calls the show() Method from Notifications.vue - It also executes the method and changes the data from the component - but the view just does not change.

Comment: But there's *no component instance*; what instance does `this` refer to inside that method? Put a breakpoint inside the `show` method and inspect the value of `this`; it's probably not what you expect.